# Retrieve checked Multiple checkboxes values in laravel controller page

Tags: php, laravel

How to get all the Checked Checkboxes values From View to Controller???

My view page code is,

```
{!! Form::checkbox('control_type[]', 001, '', array('id'=>'control_type', 'name'=>'control_type[]')) !!} {!! trans('noorsi.control_type_001') !!}</br>
{!! Form::checkbox('control_type[]', 002, '', array('id'=>'control_type', 'name'=>'control_type[]')) !!} {!! trans('noorsi.control_type_002') !!}</br>
{!! Form::checkbox('control_type[]', 003, '', array('id'=>'control_type', 'name'=>'control_type[]')) !!} {!! trans('noorsi.control_type_003') !!}
```

and my controller page code is,

```
$control_type = $request->get('control_type');
```

I just want to get the values(001,002...) of checked checkboxes... Can anyone help me...?

Answer (score 4):

In your controller you can get the values like `$request->input('control_type')`. This will be an array. Now you can loop through the array to get the individual values.

like:

```
foreach($request->input('control_type') as $value){
  // $value
}
```